# Can AJAX request data from a remote server?

Tags: javascript, ajax, request

Can I use XMLHttpRequests in JavaScript to request a file on a different server than the one from where the request was made?

Thank you.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need to use a method that is called as [JSONP](http://remysharp.com/2007/10/08/what-is-jsonp/).

One of the best ways is to use jQuery to reduce the code and worries between your page and the server, and all you need to do is:

```
$.ajax({
  dataType: 'jsonp',
  data: 'id=10',
  jsonp: 'jsonp_callback',
  url: 'http://myotherserver.com/getdata',
  success: function () {
    // do stuff
  },
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Only if the remote server supports [JSONP](http://bob.pythonmac.org/archives/2005/12/05/remote-json-jsonp/) or [HTTP `Access-Control`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTTP_access_control) headers.

*Public* JSON API's (like the ones provided by Google.com, Facebook.com, etc) often do.