# Calling an api with ajax using jquery mobile in phonegap

Tags: jquery, cordova, jquery-mobile

Actually I want to a call an php url with jQuery mobile ajax call in android phonegap. The possible outcomes of the url are

1. if successs then -- valid
2. if fails the -- Code:201

I am using this code but it is not working help me.

```
        var request = $.ajax({
            url : "http://URL.com/api/validate.php?user=myUser&password=myPassword",
            type : "GET"
        });

        request.done(function(msg) {
            $("#notification").text(request.val());
        });

        request.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
            alert("Request failed: " + textStatus);
        });
```

Comment: Are you getting an error?

Comment: no if i am using 

$("#notification").text(request);

then it is giving me [object object]

But if I am using 

$("#notification").text(request.val());

It goes to success block but shows nothing.

Comment: See this question regarding JSONP: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3897641/can-ajax-request-data-from-a-remote-server.

Comment: why don't you try with the java script Ajax call ? if you can use then i can share the code .

Comment: @neeraj please give me I will try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you can put those function in the ajax method

```
 $.ajax({
   url : "http://URL.com/api/validate.php?user=myUser&password=myPassword",
   type : "GET",
   success : function(data){/*yr code here*/},
   fail: function(){/*yr code here*/}
 });
```

Comment: But I want to get values from server response also.

Comment: Thanks @fattomhk It worked for me...... But can u provide me some explanation. Thanks for helping

Comment: They are callback functions defined by jQuery,

you may find more here:
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/