# Posting to a remote server in jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax

i'm submitting a form through ajax. it worked perfectly when the server script was hosted on my local computer. Now i've uploaded it unto my remote hosting server and it fails to do the call

when the file was on the local machine the script looked like this

```
<script language="javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("form").on('submit',function(event){
        event.preventDefault();

        data = $(this).serialize();
        $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "login.php",
        data: data
        }).success(function(msg) {
   $('#message').html(msg);


        });
    });
});

</script>
```

Remote hosting server

```
<script language="javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("form").on('submit',function(event){
        event.preventDefault();

        data = $(this).serialize();
        $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "http://mysite/login.php",
        data: data
        }).success(function(msg) {
   $('#message').html(msg);


        });
    });
});

</script>
```

Now when i click on the submit button nothing happens

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can AJAX request data from a remote server?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3897641/can-ajax-request-data-from-a-remote-server) (found by Googling "ajax remote server")

Comment: Do you load this script from your remote server?

Comment: checked the answers to the question above but doesn't work. i'm hosting on godaddy

Comment: Fire up your Javascript console and see what happens. Either you get a browser- or server-related error code.

Comment: @DeblatonJean-Philippe, yes i do the call from the remote server.

Comment: This is related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17874730/how-to-make-cross-domain-request

Answer (score 3):

First off you cannot pass post variables to different servers if that is what you are trying to do.  Just trying to clarify.  You cannot fill out a form on abc.com and run your JS / AJAX request and expect the post url to be wxy.com   If you are trying to do that it will not work.  If not.  Then simply fix the url like so.

**This:**

> ```
>     url: "http://mysite/login.php",
> ```

**Needs to be This:**

> ```
>     url: "login.php",
> ```

Assming that the location of the JS script executing the AJAX call and login.php reside in the same directory. if not, just make a relative path.  i.e.

> ```
>     url: "sub_directory/login.php",
> ```

and all will work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

For me, you are not doing any cross-site domain request, nor any other thing...

```
<script language="javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("form").on('submit',function(event){
        event.preventDefault();

        data = $(this).serialize();
        $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "login.php",
          data: data
        }).success(function(msg) {
   $('#message').html(msg);


        });
    });
});

</script>
```

Your "local" script was already good